# How does package.lock.json fileVersion go back from 2 to 1

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Can two developers with different version of npm (v5 and v7) can work together in terms of the fileLockVersion on package.lock.json files? Or do we all have to be using close to the same version? I recently upgraded npm on a new pc, and then my lock file had to go from lockVersion 1 to 2 when i cloned remote branch. Then a co-worker pushed changes and I pulled down his and it's complaining that it's going from 2 to 1.

We're all new to modern web tooling. We're just looking for strategies on how to not screw up our packages while working. Is it recommended to use npm ci instead of npm i ? But if so, then how do you upgrade a package since npm ci is supposed to be for installing all packages. Are there any good articles that provide some direction or rules for co-development with package and package.lock files? Apologies if this is naive but I didn't find anything regarding team best practices.

Comment: You should both be using the same version or node and npm. Just asking for trouble otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I needed someone with personal experience to say that. Been to a million sites and couldn't find a decent actionable answer.